# git cannot push an existing repository. 'remote-httpshttps' is not a git command

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, git-repo

Failed to push existing git repository to remote.

It did not happen before. I have tried install the last version of git but still fail to push.

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
git: 'remote-httpshttps' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Comment: You have just a new branch (`master`) that you want to push? Or how should to understand `"git cannot push an existing repository..."`. Or is the `master` branch already a *remote-branch*?

Comment: `remote-httpshttps` is rather suspicious. Please see `git remote show origin` and fix the URL by removing double `httpshttps://`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why..... I closed the git bash, and opened a new one. Then it was fixed:(

Answer (score 0):

If you have the HTTPS URL of your remote repository, try first:

```
git remote set-url origin https://url/of/remote/repository
```

Then try again the `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: actually whatever git command i give, it always `git: 'remote-httpshttps' is not a git command.` ... and it was just fixed by re-opening a new bash:(